# Rooted but su says “Permission denied”

Tags: rooting

[ I first asked this question on stackoverflow by mistake.  ]

I have this "old" Lenovo A2107 tablet which I rooted years ago (using a download from http://androidforums.com/threads/a2107-root-mods-and-rom-discussion.661261/, tho running its root.bat script by hand from my GNU/Linux machine) and that worked fine: I could "su" from the shell and then edit all the files I wanted.

Then I passed this tablet to my daughter for a couple years, and now I got it back.

/system/bin/su is still present, still the same date and size, still mode "rwsr-sr-x", still the same firmware (Android 4.0.3) so all looks fine, but when I try to run it from a shell, it just tells me "Permission denied".  And of course, other applications that require root bump into the same problem.

Any idea what might be going on? What I could try to do to track it down?

[ See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353148 where I posted the solution I encountered.  ]

Comment: have you tried a root checker app as they can be good to detect a possible issue?

Comment: re-root. repeat the procedure that you used first time. that should do the trick.

Comment: @iTechy: RootChecker just tells me that my machine is not rooted.

Comment: Try
adb shell su
mount -o remount,rw /system

Comment: Then you will need to re root

Comment: @BoLawson: Thanks, I didn't expect it, but oddly enough, indeed "su" works from "adb shell".  So it's still *somewhat* rooted.

Comment: Good stuff, I figured at least a shell should still be available. Because from what I have seen its just the one-click and root apps that cause permissions  to mysteriously disappear.

Comment: Did you find the solution